# rails 4 bundle install with nested form master branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following in my gem file

```
gem 'nested_form', :git => "git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git", :branch => '0-3-stable'
```

When i give `bundle install` in local it is working fine. But while deploying using capistrano
getting following error

```
Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'
```

It I use `gem 'nested_form'` alone, In local getting error as

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'jquery_nested_form'
```

Can anyone help how to solve this issue

**Edit-1**

my local system ruby version

```
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]
```

and my server ruby version is

```
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
```

both same.

My bundle gem in local is

```
bundler (1.3.5) and bundler-unload (1.0.1)
```

In server it is

```
bundler (1.3.5) and bundler-unload (1.0.2)
```

Comment: same version of ruby on both systems, same version of bundler on both?

Comment: @Doon Can you please check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Is it a public repository?

Change `git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git`

Into `https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git`

If the repository is private, you will need to [enable user keys](https://circleci.com/account/ssh) from your account settings.

Comment: Because your local has an ssh access to your git account

Comment: Ok if i add my server ssh to my git account it will work right?

Comment: It is a public repository, so its enough to change it to https

Comment: Same error occurs in server but working in local. Here is the error `Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'`

Comment: Have you change your Gemfile like this -
`gem 'nested_form', :git => "https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git"` ?